# How to generate dynamic HTML from HTML string?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a piece of code which is generating HTML content dynamically, here is the code:

```
var content='<input type="text" placeholder="text type">'+Sample Text;
this.htmlContent=content;
```

But the result which I am getting is only the text written as "Sample Text" and not the input type text box. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your `input` is missing a closing `/`. That's probably messing up the DOM addition.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: @Cerbrus Nopes . This is not the issue . It is not making any difference to the output.

Comment: @messerbill Nopes this solution is also not working.

Comment: @Cerbrus `input` is a void element, so it can't have a content, thus don't needs a closing tag at all

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas: No, a closing ___tag___ isn't allowed, but for (x)html compliance, closing the tag itself is recommended, and can sometimes prevent parsing issues.  Bad: `<input type="text"></input>`. Good: `<input type="text" />`

Comment: try to put your text in a span element.
like:
var content= `<input type="text" placeholder="text type"> <span> ${Sample Text} </span>`;

Comment: this is exactly what you are searching for....you cannot simply add a string as a component due to it will not be interpreted as such. You need to have something like a factory hence why i posted that link above

Comment: @Cerbrus I may believe that closing tag is recommended for XHTML compliance, because of XML standards. However I don't believe that closing tag is recommended for HTML5 standard in void elements. Can you give some online reference for this argument ?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas: It depends on who you ask and what doctype you're looking to support.

Comment: Agree. If we are going to support HTML5 - then, as i've said before, closing tag isn't needed for void elements. But of course it's recommended for XHTML.